# Clear Phonegap's InAppBrowser Cache

Tags: javascript, cordova, caching, inappbrowser

I am using Google authorization into my app. It works perfectly,
but the problem is cache not clear when someone logout from app.

I have tried adding `clearcache=yes` and `clearsessioncache=yes`, but they do not seem to do anything. Without clearing the cache when someone tries to log back in it validates the token with the previously signed in account.

Is there a way I can delete everything associated to the InAppBrowser ?

```
 var googleapi = {
    authorize: function (options) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        //Build the OAuth consent page URL
        var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?' + $.param({
            client_id: options.client_id,
            redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
            response_type: 'code',
            scope: options.scope

        });

 var authWindow = window.open(authUrl,'_blank','location=no,toolbar=no,clearsessioncache=yes');

        $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function (e) {
            var url = e.originalEvent.url;
            var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
            var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);

            if (code || error) {
                //Always close the browser when match is found
                authWindow.close();
            }

            if (code) {
                //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
                $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                    code: code[1],
                    client_id: options.client_id,
                    client_secret: options.client_secret,
                    redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                }).done(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);

                    $("#loginStatus").html('Name: ' + data.given_name);
                }).fail(function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                });
            } else if (error) {
                //The user denied access to the app
                deferred.reject({
                    error: error[1]
                });
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise();
    }
};
var accessToken;
var UserData = null;
function callGoogle() {

    googleapi.authorize({
        client_id: 'client_id',
        client_secret: 'client_secret-key',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost',
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    }).done(function (data) {
        accessToken = data.access_token;
        getDataProfile();
    });

}
function getDataProfile() {
    var term = null;       
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + accessToken,
        type: 'GET',
        data: term,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (jqXHR, text_status, strError) {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var item;
            var OAuthToken = accessToken;
            var OAuthAccessToken = data.id;
            var username = data.email;
            var firstname = data.given_name;
            var lastname = data.family_name;
            var ExternalIdentifier = data.id;
            var Email = data.email;
            var ProviderSystemName = "ExternalAuth.Google";

            ExternalResponseInsert(apiSecretKey, storeId, languageId, username, firstname, lastname, Email, ExternalIdentifier, OAuthToken, OAuthAccessToken, ProviderSystemName);
        }
    });
    //disconnectUser();
}
function disconnectUser() {
    var revokeUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=' + accessToken;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: revokeUrl,
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (nullResponse) {
          accessToken = null;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(nullResponse));
            console.log("-----signed out..!!----" + accessToken);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            // Handle the error

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you post all the inAppBrowser call code? In which platform are you testing?

Comment: @jcesarmobile  you can find inAppBrowser call code in question. and i'm testing in android and ios both

Comment: Hey, did you get this problem resolved? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown: Sorry, this is too old post, I'm not sure about what was the issue at that time! if you found an answer please add it here also

Comment: mine was I put a space between `toolbar=no, clearsessioncache=yes`. I see that you have no space.